# Don't call popup if another one is already on the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

There is a `popup (1)` that should be called after 15 seconds of being on the page.
But if the user opened some other `popup(2)`, then don't call the first one.

popup(1);

```
mounted() {
 this.openModal();
},

// methods
openModal() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.isModalVisible = true;
  }, 15000);
},
```

How to do it?
Perhaps need to stop `setTimeOut`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      isModalVisible: false,
      isModalOther: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openModal() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(!this.isModalOther) this.isModalVisible = true;
      }, 5000);
    },
    openOtherModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = false
      this.isModalOther = true;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
   this.openModal();
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-if="isModalVisible">popup1</div>
  <div v-if="isModalOther">popup2</div>
  <button @click="openOtherModal">open popup2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If I have the first and second popup in different components, is there a way to keep track?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a timeout, all you need to do is call `clearTimeout(TimeoutID);`. A timeoutID is a returned by the `setTimeout()` method automatically, so just save it in a variable

```
let timer = setTimeout(...);
```

then, when you call popup(2), just add

```
this.clearTimeout(timer);
```

and the first popup won't show